# access to ttyusb0 as normal user

Tags: terminal, tty, serial-console

I am trying to access a serial device, which is attached as: "/dev/ttyUSB0".

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Nov 29 15:45 ttyUSB0
```

For that I created a new udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTR{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTR{idProduct}=="7523", SYMLINK+="ttyPWM0", MODE="0666"
```

So I get the following file:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov 29 15:45 ttyPWM0 -> ttyUSB0
```

If I try to access it with echo, I get the following message. The same problem is with sudo:

```
$echo "hello" >> ttyPWM0
bash: ttyPWM0: Permission denied
```

My Question is: how can I access this file as normal user? I need to run a program with access granted to it.
I don't to add my account to dialout, because I know there is a way without doing this security hole.

---

I have a device of SalaeLogic. For this device, there is a script:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTR{idVendor}=="0925", ATTR{idProduct}=="3881", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTR{idVendor}=="21a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="1001", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTR{idVendor}=="21a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="1003", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTR{idVendor}=="21a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="1004", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTR{idVendor}=="21a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="1005", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTR{idVendor}=="21a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="1006", MODE="0666"
```

With this rule(s), I can start the program and access the device without any other action needed.
The same I would like to achieve.... but how?

Answer (score -1):

My solution meanwhile:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="ttyPWM0"
```

Comment: we are expecting answer to be in english, and with some explanation, not just a mere line of code.